# Find the value(s) of the constants C and λ

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Find the value(s) of the constants C and λ for which

$\theta_1$(t)=$e^{t\lambda}$  and $\theta_2$(t)=$Ce^{t\lambda}$

is a solution to the equations of motion

$$2\ddot\theta_1+\ddot\theta_2 + \frac{2g}{1}\theta_1=0$$

$$\ddot\theta_1+\ddot\theta_2 + \frac{g}{1}\theta_2=0$$

I began by making them equal to each other to see if that would help but all I got was

$$\ddot\theta_1+\frac{2g}{1}\theta_1=  \frac{g}{1}\theta_2$$

and I don't know where to go from here or if it is even in the right direction.

please feel free to add tags I wasn't certain what one would fit this topic all help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just insert them into the DEs: $(e^{\lambda t})''=\lambda^2 e^{\lambda t}$ and $(Ce^{\lambda t})''=C\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}$, so we have: $$2\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+C\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+2ge^{\lambda t}=0\implies(2+C)\lambda^2+2g=0\tag1$$
$$\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+C\lambda^2e^{\lambda t}+gCe^{\lambda t}=0\implies(1+C)\lambda^2+gC=0\tag2$$

Solve this pair and you have your $\lambda$ and $C$.

Comment: your answer looks right but i have been trying to get what lambda and C are with it but cannot seem to get any nice answers i was wondering if you had, had better luck?

Comment: @sufferingmathsstudent  I believe you should be getting two values for $ \ C \ $ (plus and minus) and two distinct _negative_ values for $ \ \lambda^2 \ $ , since this is an _oscillatory_ system with two modes ( $ \ \lambda \ $ _should_ be imaginary).